# How to query Navision database

Tags: navision

I need to export some tables from Navision. It is configured to use the local datastore, not an SQL Server.

How can I connect to and dump these tables?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this technology, but this looks promising: http://www.mibuso.com/dlinfo.asp?FileID=350

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have navision, you'll also have the `NODBC` driver on the install DVD, which should enable you to query it with a SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Navision offers extensive exporting to tab delimited files from within the program.

Comment: The raw table dumps have been requested by auditors, unless navision can export to csv the raw tables, that isn't going to help.

Comment: With a Dataport you can do exactly this. You can even export multiple tables with one dataport.